# Flexslider jQuery plugin won't run slideshow

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am a refactoring code for a website I am making and I am trying to use Flexslider jQuery plugin instead of AnythingSlider plugin I was originally used. I downloaded the plugin and followed the directions on the website ([Flexslider website](https://woocommerce.com/flexslider/)) for how to get started with the plugin. However, the pictures in the ul class "slides" are still in a list form and don't appear as a slideshow. Here is my current code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 /*
 alert('Our JavaScriipt is working!');
 console.log('Our Javascript is working!');
 console.warn('A dire warning!');
 console.error('ERMAGERD AN ERROR!');
 */

   var modalContainer = $("#modal-container");

   var hideModal = function() {
     modalContainer.hide();
    };

    var showModal = function() {
     modalContainer.show();
    };

    var modalShowButton = $("#modal-show");
    modalShowButton.on("click", showModal);

    var modalCloseButton = $("#modal-hide");
    modalCloseButton.on("click", hideModal);

    $(document).on("keyup", function(evt) {
      evt = evt || window.event;

      if (evt.keyCode === 27) {
       hideModal();
      }
    });

    var handleNewsletterSignup = function(evt) {
      evt.preventDefault();

      var newsletterHeader = $("#newsletter-header");

      var newsletterForm = $("#newsletter-signup");
      newsletterForm.hide();

      newsletterHeader.text("Thank you for signing up!");

      setTimeout(hideModal, 2000);
};

    var newsletterForm = $("#newsletter-signup");
    newsletterForm.on("submit", handleNewsletterSignup);

/* Begin the clock code */

   var clockTime = function() {
    var currentTime = new Date();

    var hours = currentTime.getHours();
    var minutes = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var seconds = currentTime.getSeconds();

    if (hours <= 11) {
     var period = "AM";
    } else {
     var period = "PM";
    }

    if (hours > 12) {
     hours = hours - 12;
    } else if (hours === 0) {
     hours = 12;
    }

    if (minutes < 10) {
     minutes = "0" + String(minutes);
    }

    if (seconds < 10) {
     seconds = "0" + String(seconds);
    }

    var time = hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds + ' ' + period;

    return time;
   }

   var clock = $("#clock");

   setInterval(function() {
    clock.text(clockTime());
   }, 1000);



});
```

```html
 <head>
  <title>Liz Lemon's Personal Website</title>
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Gloria+Hallelujah|Open+Sans:400italic,400,700|Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
      
  <script src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
  <script src="jQuery.flexslider.js"></script>
  
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
 $(window).load(function() {
   $('.flexslider').flexslider({;
  animation: "slide",
  animationLoop: true,
  slideshow: true;
  randomize: false,
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="page">
    <header>
      <h1>Liz Lemon's Personal Website</h1>
      <img id="headshot" src="http://i284.photobucket.com/albums/ll14/britishpandachick/liz-lemon_zps6qncghn4.jpg" alt="Headshot">
    </header>

    <h4>
      The current time is...
      <span id="clock">Clock goes here</span>
    </h4>

    <blockquote id="greeting">This is where the JavaScript greeting goes...</blockquote>
    
    <section id="bio">
      <h2>About me</h2>
      <p>Here is a paragraph all about how awesome I am. Don't you <em>love</em> to read about me? Hmm, not so much? Well, then replace this paragraph with some information about <strong>yourself</strong>! Or you can go read some fun articles on <a href="http://www.skillcrush.com" alt="Skillcrush.com">Skillcrush</a>.
      </p>
    </section>
   
   <div class="flexslider">
    <ul class="slides">
     <li><img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/14900000/S1-Promotional-Photos-Liz-Lemon-liz-lemon-14945184-1071-1500.jpg" alt="professional_pic"/></li>
     <li><img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1362193/original.jpg" alt="fun_pic"/></li>
     <li><img src="http://cdn.pastemagazine.com/www/blogs/lists/lizlemonthumbs.jpg" alt="thumbs_up"/></li>
    </ul>
  </div>

    <section id="contact">
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <div id="social-icons">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://i284.photobucket.com/albums/ll14/britishpandachick/twitter_zpsulfh8can.png" alt="Twitter icon">
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>
    
    <button id="modal-show">Join the Lemon List</button>
    <div id="modal-container">
     <section id="modal-box">
      <button id="modal-hide">x</button>
       <h2 id="newsletter-header">Sign up for my email list!</h2>
       <form id="newsletter-signup" action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
        <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your email">
        <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
       </form>
     </section>
    </div>
    
    <footer>
      <p>&copy; Skillcrush 2014</p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  </body>
```

So far I have triple checked every single part of my code (especially what is in the head) with the sample ones on the website and github. I also tried moving some of the JS to the JS file. Despite these changes, the pictures in slides class remain a bullet point list. Did I link the wrong files for flexslider? I think my issue is with the HTML section, but I'm not 100% positive since my code looks the same as the ones on the sample page.

Comment: It took me a few days, but I finally got the slide show to work. I just changed the plugin I was using and reading the plugin documentation. I think the problem was in the HTML and the links I used in the link tags. I might play with my code again in the future to see if I can get flexslider to work some day in the future.

Answer (score 0):

I think error in your CSS and JS inclusion.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="flexslider.css" type="text/css">
<script src="jQuery.flexslider.js"></script>
```

Like it should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.domain.com/myphysicaldirectory/js/jQuery.flexslider.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.domain.com/myphysicaldirectory/css/flexslider.css" media="all" />
```

Set your JS and CSS Path properly and open your source code (ctrl + u) and check its include properly or not. also check included path open correctly in browser or not.

Comment: I did what you suggested and changed the JS and CSS paths then opened the source code to triple check, but the slideshow still isn't working. I am double checking the files in the zip file I downloaded from the site.

Comment: Download this https://github.com/woocommerce/FlexSlider and open demo folder and run its file in browser. Set your HTML accordingly.

Comment: I re-downloaded the plugin from the link you sent and ran the file index in the demo folder on the browser. I made changes to my code and double check to see if everything was set up correctly. When I ran everything in the browser, the pictures are still in a bullet point list and not in a slide show.

Comment: i put your code in demo folder and create one test file. its running fine. Check my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

When you download flexslider zip file then inside that demo folder, create one test.html file and add below code in it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta content="charset=utf-8">
    <title>Liz Lemon's Personal Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0">   

  <!-- Demo CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/demo.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../flexslider.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

    <!-- Modernizr -->
  <script src="js/modernizr.js"></script>

</head>
<body class="loading">

  <div id="container" class="cf">
    <header>
      <h1>Liz Lemon's Personal Website</h1>
      <img id="headshot" src="http://i284.photobucket.com/albums/ll14/britishpandachick/liz-lemon_zps6qncghn4.jpg" alt="Headshot">
    </header>
    <h4>
      The current time is...
      <span id="clock">Clock goes here</span>
    </h4>

    <blockquote id="greeting">This is where the JavaScript greeting goes...</blockquote>

    <section id="bio">
      <h2>About me</h2>
      <p>Here is a paragraph all about how awesome I am. Don't you <em>love</em> to read about me? Hmm, not so much? Well, then replace this paragraph with some information about <strong>yourself</strong>! Or you can go read some fun articles on <a href="http://www.skillcrush.com" alt="Skillcrush.com">Skillcrush</a>.
      </p>
    </section>

    <div id="main" role="main">
      <section class="slider">
        <div class="flexslider carousel">
          <ul class="slides">
            <li>
                <img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/14900000/S1-Promotional-Photos-Liz-Lemon-liz-lemon-14945184-1071-1500.jpg" alt="professional_pic"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1362193/original.jpg" alt="fun_pic"/>
                </li>  
                <li>
                <img src="http://cdn.pastemagazine.com/www/blogs/lists/lizlemonthumbs.jpg" alt="thumbs_up"/>
                </li>               
            <li>
                <img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/14900000/S1-Promotional-Photos-Liz-Lemon-liz-lemon-14945184-1071-1500.jpg" alt="professional_pic"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1362193/original.jpg" alt="fun_pic"/>
                </li>  
                <li>
                <img src="http://cdn.pastemagazine.com/www/blogs/lists/lizlemonthumbs.jpg" alt="thumbs_up"/>
                </li> 
            <li>
                <img src="http://images4.fanpop.com/image/photos/14900000/S1-Promotional-Photos-Liz-Lemon-liz-lemon-14945184-1071-1500.jpg" alt="professional_pic"/>
                </li>
                <li>
                <img src="http://i.huffpost.com/gen/1362193/original.jpg" alt="fun_pic"/>
                </li>  
                <li>
                <img src="http://cdn.pastemagazine.com/www/blogs/lists/lizlemonthumbs.jpg" alt="thumbs_up"/>
                </li> 
          </ul>
        </div>
      </section>

      <section id="contact">
      <h2>Contact</h2>
      <div id="social-icons">
        <a href="#">
          <img src="http://i284.photobucket.com/albums/ll14/britishpandachick/twitter_zpsulfh8can.png" alt="Twitter icon">
        </a>
      </div>
    </section>

    <button id="modal-show">Join the Lemon List</button>
    <div id="modal-container">
        <section id="modal-box">
            <button id="modal-hide">x</button>
                <h2 id="newsletter-header">Sign up for my email list!</h2>
                <form id="newsletter-signup" action="#" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8">
                    <input type="email" name="email" value="" placeholder="Your email">
                    <input type="submit" value="Sign up">
                </form>
        </section>
    </div>

    <footer>
      <p>&copy; Skillcrush 2014</p>
    </footer>

    </div>

  </div>

  <!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/libs/jquery-1.7.min.js">\x3C/script>')</script>

  <!-- FlexSlider -->
  <script defer src="../jquery.flexslider.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).load(function(){
      $('.flexslider').flexslider({
        animation: "slide",
        animationLoop: false,
        itemWidth: 420,
        itemMargin: 1,
        pausePlay: true,
        start: function(slider){
          $('body').removeClass('loading');
        }
      });
    });
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I already test it. its running fine.